# bootstrap| place a navbar inside col

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

im new in bootstrap and im trying to make a navbar inside a grid.

HTML:

```
    <div class="container-fluid" id="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-9 pull-left">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body div#header{
width:100%;
padding-bottom:514px;
background-image:url("../images/topbg.png");
background-size: cover  ;
background-position:center; }
```

code;

The main container-fluid have background-image.
npw the problem is when i resize the browser for mobile resolution the nav get smaller, i debug the code and i relize that its happen because i place the nav inside "col-md-9".

is it the right way to place a navbar on background-image?

here the code online:
[http://צבעיבאשקלון.co.il/stack/](http://%D7%A6%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%91%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9F.co.il/stack/)

Comment: `col-`' must be nested within a `row`. You should not be using `container-` _within_ the grid - it should be the outer most element. You should not be using `container-` within another `container-`. It looks like you should probably go back to the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) and learn the basics of the Bootstrap grid system as you are not using it correctly at the moment.

Comment: ill do that, can u show me how to fix this?
@turnip

Comment: I mentioned three issues that need to be fixed in my last comment. You should be able to fix those yourself.

Comment: ok, i didnt understand what do u mean "ou should not be using container- within another container-"
i updated the file can u see it? @turnip